# When provisioning with Terraform, how does code obtain a reference to machine IDs (e.g. database machine address)

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

Let's say I'm using Terraform to provision two machines inside AWS:

- An EC2 Machine running NodeJS
- An RDS instance

How does the NodeJS code obtain the address of the RDS instance?

Comment: You need spend time to read the documents in terraform, I mean `one by one` of them. Here is the start for your question: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of options here. The simplest one is to create a CNAME record in Route53 for the database and then always point to that CNAME in your application.

A basic example would look something like this:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "mydb" {
  allocated_storage    = 10
  engine               = "mysql"
  engine_version       = "5.6.17"
  instance_class       = "db.t2.micro"
  name                 = "mydb"
  username             = "foo"
  password             = "bar"
  db_subnet_group_name = "my_database_subnet_group"
  parameter_group_name = "default.mysql5.6"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "database" {
   zone_id = "${aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id}"
   name = "database.example.com"
   type = "CNAME"
   ttl = "300"
   records = ["${aws_db_instance.default.endpoint}"]
}
```

Alternative options include taking the `endpoint` output from the `aws_db_instance` and passing that into a user data script when creating the instance or passing it to [Consul](https://www.consul.io/) and using Consul Template to control the config that your application uses.

Comment: It is a good sample for new start user, but using keyword `default` is misleading in this sample.

Comment: I simply lifted the examples from Terraform's docs but fair enough. Updated the name

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Sparrowform](https://github.com/melezhik/sparrowform) - a lightweight provision tool for Terraform based instances, it's capable to make an inventory of Terraform resources and provision related hosts, passing all the necessary data:

```
$ terrafrom apply # bootstrap infrastructure

$ cat sparrowfile # this scenario
                  # fetches DB address from terraform cache 
                  # and populate configuration file 
                  # at server with node js code:

#!/usr/bin/env perl6

use Sparrowform;

$ sparrowfrom --ssh_private_key=~/.ssh/aws.pem --ssh_user=ec2 # run provision tool

my $rdb-adress; 

for tf-resources() -> $r {
  my $r-id = $r[0]; # resource id
  if ( $r-id 'aws_db_instance.mydb') {
    my $r-data = $r[1];                
    $rdb-address = $r-data<address>;
    last;
  }
}

# For instance, we can 
# Install configuration file
# Next chunk of code will be applied to  
# The server with node-js code: 

template-create '/path/to/config/app.conf', %(
  source => ( slurp 'app.conf.tmpl' ),
  variables => %(
    rdb-address => $rdb-address
  ),
);

# sparrowform --ssh_private_key=~/.ssh/aws.pem --ssh_user=ec2 # run provisioning
```

PS. disclosure - I am the tool author